# Tamanho máximo de solicitação ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo upload de Imagem usando JQuery.

Limitei a imagem para no màximo 2mb, porém ao enviar imagem maior de 2mb aparece uma excessão dizendo Tamanho máximo de solicitação excedido.

Isso que eu fiz:

```js
function fileUpload() {
    
    $('#fileupload').fileupload();
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024,
        autoupload: true
    });

    var uploadFinished = function (e, data) {
        if (data.files[0].size > 2000000) { // 2mb
            $.notify("Faça o upload de uma imagem de até 2MB", "danger");
            jqXHR.abort();
            return
        }

        var img = $("#inpLogoNameNew").val();
        $("#imgLogo").show();
        $("#imgWhite").hide();
        $("#imgLogo").attr("src", (data.result.imgx64));
        $("#inpLogoNameNew").val(data.result.Name);

        if ($("#inpLogoNameOld").val() !== $("#inpLogoNameNew").val() &&
            img !== $("#inpLogoNameNew").val() &&
            img !== $("#inpLogoNameOld").val()) {
            deleteLogo(img);
        }

    };
    $('#fileupload')
        .bind('fileuploaddone', uploadFinished);
}
```

```html
<form id="fileupload" action="@Url.Action("UploadFiles")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <span id="spanUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fileinput-button"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i><span>Foto</span>
                        <input id="inpLogo" type="file" name="files[]"/>
                    </span>
                </form>
```

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No `Web.Config`, defina o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
  </system.webServer>
    ...
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Estes são os valores mais altos que já usei (1 gigabyte). Bom dizer:

- `maxAllowedContentLength` é em *bytes*;
- `maxRequestLength` é em *kilobytes*.

Comment: estou com esse mesmo problema e não consegui resolver usando esse código. alguma sugestão?

Comment: Este código não resolve, é preciso alterar o `maxRequestLength` da entrada `httpRuntime` conforme informado noutras respostas.

Answer (score 3):

Estava com o mesmo problema e não consegui resolver com a solução do Cigano. Resolvi inserindo o seguinte código no `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime 
executionTimeout="90" 
maxRequestLength="4096" //aumentar o valor aqui
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
minFreeThreads="8" 
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
appRequestQueueLimit="100"
/>
```

Vou deixar salvo aqui pra ajudar outras pessoas também.

Comment: Seria bom você detalhar também quais são as tags pai, como fiz na minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

No web config, já existe uma configuração:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
```

Basta alterar, ficara assim:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10485760"/>
</system.web>
```

Assim funciona

Comment: Fala Harry, fazia uma semana que estava com esse problema quase. Obrigada pela ajuda. Deus abençoe mestre jedi.

Comment: @MarianeRibeiro, e um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Basta você realizar a alteração na sua `web.config`, fincando assim:

```
< system.web><br>
    < httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"/> <br>
< / system.web>
```

O valor é definido em kilobytes e o padrão é de 4096, ou seja, 4 megabytes. Acima, por exemplo, o tamanho máximo foi definido como 10 megabytes.

Answer (score -1):

tive este problema:

**System.Web.HttpException: O comprimento da cadeia de caracteres de consulta para essa solicitação excede o valor maxQueryStringLength configurado.**

resolvi assim (tenha em mente que o valor dos atributos maxRequestLength, maxQueryStringLength e maxQueryString podem ser diferentes para a sua aplicação. Basta testar):

**no web.config**

coloque esta linha em system.web

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10240"  maxQueryStringLength="32768"  />
</system.web>
```

e em system.webServer, coloque

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

pra mim funcionou assim.
Espero ter ajudado.